# How to initialize multiple objects in java as inline class initialization

Tags: java

I have following data source:

```
"resource_access": {
    "hbg-dept": {
      "roles": [
        "admin",
        "manager"
        
      ]
    }
  },
```

To create a data model out of the above data source, I have created two class. Like:

```
public class ResourceAccess {
  private HbgDept hbg_dept;
}

public class HbgDept {
  private List<String> roles;
}
```

And I am using ResourceAccess as a property in my UserDetails class.

```
public class UserDetails {
  private String name;
  private String preferred_username;
  private String given_name;
  private String family_name;
  private String email;
  private ResourceAccess resource_access;
}
```

But, when I try to embed data in resource_access in the UserDetails class. I need to initialize as follows:

```
HbgDept vwagKums = new HbgDept ();
HbgDept.setRoles(roleList);

ResourceAccess resourceAccess = new ResourceAccess();
resourceAccess.sethbg_dept(vwagKums);

userDetails.setResource_access(resourceAccess);
```

My question is, this why everything is working fine. But, is there some other way to initialize some better way? May be inline? I came from C# where I can initialize inline. But here I can not do so.

Comment: Not inline, but using the builder pattern makes it [fluent](https://www.baeldung.com/java-fluent-interface-vs-builder-pattern).

Comment: You can take parameters in the Constructuor. Then you won't have to use setter. You would be able to write `userDetails.setResource_access(new ResourceAccess(new HbgDept (roleList)));`

Comment: But I can not set roleList.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that something like this can be done, but is not pretty:

`userDetails.setResource_access(new ResourceAccess(new HbgDept(roleList)));`

Another option can be:

````
public class UserDetails {
    ...
    public void init_resource_access(List<whatever-type> roleList) {
        resource_access = new ResourceAccess(new HbgDept(roleList)); 
    }
...
}

// use it as
userDetails.init_resource_access(roleList);
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Make *HbgDept* the inner-class of *ResourceAccess*.

```java
class ResourceAccess {
    private HbgDept hbg_dept;

    ResourceAccess(List<String> roles) {
        hbg_dept = new HbgDept();
        hbg_dept.setRoles(roleList);
    }

    class HbgDept {
        private List<String> roles;
    }
}
```

```java
userDetails.setResource_access(new ResourceAccess(roleList));
```